# Bash detect 1st input parameter is "debug"?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to detect if the 1st bash input parameter is "debug"(string).

I write script like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq "1" && "$1" -eq "debug" ]; then
    echo "hello debug"
fi
```

Error message:

```
line 3: [: missing `]'
```

I don't know why, please help.

Comment: There's no real need to test `$#` here; you can ignore additional arguments if present, and if `$#` is 0, then `"$1" = debug` will be false since `$1` expands to the empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare strings with `==`, `-eq` is an arithmetic operator. Also, within `[]` you have to use the `-a` operator instead of `&&`, or split it in two. Here are a few different ways to write the same thing:

```
if [[ $# -eq 1 && "$1" == "debug" ]] ; then
    echo "hello debug"
fi
```

```
if [[ "$#" == "1" && "$1" == "debug" ]] ; then
    echo "hello debug"
fi
```

```
if [ "$#" == "1" ] && [ "$1" == "debug" ] ; then
    echo "hello debug"
fi
```

```
if [ "$#" == "1" -a "$1" == "debug" ] ; then
    echo "hello debug"
fi
```

Comment: Splitting in two is preferable; `-a` is non-standard and considered obsolete by POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `[ "$#" -eq "1" && "$1" -eq "debug" ]`, use either `[ "$#" -eq "1" ] && [ "$1" -eq "debug" ]` (recommended; see https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2166) or `[ "$#" -eq "1" -a "$1" -eq "debug" ]`. The problem is that `&&` is bash's way of saying "and", rather than `-a`, which is test's way of saying "and". You can't use a bash "and" inside of test.